# I have InvalidArgumentException when I make database seeding

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a Restful API. I have an exception message when I want to make seeding fake data in database.

- I make database fresh.

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

- I'm seeding on database.

```
php artisan db:seed
```

I make a model with migration and controller:

- Migration: 000000_create_posts_table.php

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->string('title');
$table->text('content');

$table->dateTime('date_written');

$table->String('feature_image')->unllable();
$table->integer('votes_up')->unllable();
$table->integer('votes_down')->unllable();

// TelationShipe.
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('category_id');

$table->timestamps();
});
```

- Model: Post.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Post extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
    'title' , 'content' , 'date_written' ,
    'feature_image' , 'votes_up' ,
    'votes_down' , 'user_id' ,
    'category_id'
    ];
}
```

- Controller: PostController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PostController extends Controller {
//
}
```

- Seeder: DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
        factory(\App\Post::class , 100 )->create();
    }
}
```

- Factory: PostFactory.php

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
use App\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This directory should contain each of the model factory definitions for
| your application. Factories provide a convenient way to generate new
| model instances for testing / seeding your application's database.
|
*/

$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->title,
        'content' => $faker->text(400),
        'date_written' => $faker->new(),
        'feature_image' => $faker->imageUrl(),
        'votes_up' => $faker->numberBetween(1 , 100),
        'votes_down' => $faker->numberBetween(1 , 100),
        'user_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1 , 15),
        'category_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1 , 15),
    ];
});
```

- but the actual output console:

```
InvalidArgumentException:  
Unknown formatter "new" at ~/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:242
    238| 
    239|                 return $this->formatters[$formatter];
    240|             }
    241|         }
    242|         throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unknown formatter "%s"', $formatter));
    243|     }
    244| 
    245|     /**
              * Replaces tokens ('{{ tokenName }}') with the result 
              * from the token method call
              */

  Exception trace:

  1   Faker\Generator::getFormatter("new")
      ~/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:222

  2   Faker\Generator::format("new", [])
      ~/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:279

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: also you are probably looking for `nullable()` in your migrations not `unllable()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

From

```php
'date_written' => $faker->new(),
```

To

```php
'date_written' => now(),
```

[now()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-now) will return a Carbon instance of the current time which your database migration require

> There's no such function on faker generator called `new`